# How to assign a response of requests inside a loop to array in node

Tags: node.js

I tried to make multiple requests inside a for loop and that loop inside a promise function now i want to return the responses from request after completion of all requests but, i didn't find async false option for request module.

```
var upload_multiple = function(image_path) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                
        var slices = 6;
        
        var request = require('request');
        _ids = [];

        for(var x=0; x < slices; x++){
                
            var cropped_image = gm(image_path)
            .crop(width, height/6, 0, (height/6)*x)
            .stream('png');

            var options = {
                url: 'https://imageupload.io',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'image/png'
                },
                body: cropped_image
            };
            
            request(options, (error, response, body, resolve) => {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    var body_parse = JSON.parse(body);
                    _ids[x] = body_parse._id;
                }
            });             
        
            if(x == 5){
                resolve(_ids);
            }
        }   

      });
    
        }
        
    upload_multiple(image_path)
        .then(ids=>{
            console.log(ids);
            
            });
```

but, its not return in array of ids. Please, help to fix this issue

Comment: Use `for...of` loop instead

Comment: use  Promise.all.deal the response in the callback .

Comment: @xMayank I tried for (x of [0,1,2,3,4,5]) but, its not working

Comment: @JingJiang I'm new to Node can you provide any references

Comment: refer： https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all